# bug php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Ive struggled with a bug which I can simplify to this:-

if I set a variable $test in php and try to access it in javascript it sometimes works, but often doesnt

Im using alert to display the data in javascript... alert( php tag  echo $test; close php tag ) if it doesn't show below

```
<script>
 alert(<?php echo $test; ?>);
</script>
```

example, if in php I set $test="hello"; it does not work. Nothing!
but if I set $test=time(); it does work

why cant I set a simple string and access it in javascript? Its strange it can access a more complicated timestamp but not a string!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too unprofessional question that litters the quality of SO

Comment: Some people are so mean on here num8er! Luckily not everyone

Comment: go learn programming and then rethink Your question, hope You'll feel the shame and delete it.

Comment: well if you think its so simple then maybe you could advise why it doesn't work when I set $text=get_file_contents('myfile.txt');
makes no sense why that doesn't work since others do now.
p.s. I have a BSc Computer Science

Comment: For lazy ones who don't know word `escaping`, `converting`, `working with strings` here is solution: `$text = ' " ' . htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('myfile.txt')) . ' " ';`

Comment: You must convert Your data to be safely parsed by JS code. You're too lazy to debug and analyze Your problem. And You came here and saying  You're BSc (:   I've Master degree in Telecommunication. But why I don't ask such shame questions?

Comment: Thanks, does seem very complicated given file_get_contents was supposed to return a string!

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell JavaScript that you want to alert a string.

```
alert('<?php echo $test; ?>');
```

Notice the quotes wrapped around the PHP statement.

Comment: That's right. And the reason why it worked with _$test=time()_ is because JavaScript can evaluate a number but not a variable (like hello) that is not bound to a value.

Comment: ok that's solved that, but Im still getting nothing if I use in PHP
$text=file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
file_get_contents is supposed to return a string, and the file exists, but it makes whole program not work??

Answer (score 0):

You're missing out "".Try this instead.

```
<script>
alert("<?=$test?>");
</script>
```

Comment: can you use <?= rather than <?php
whats the difference?

Comment: <?= is shorter. It does exactly the same job.

Comment: Thank you. Ive not quite fixed my problem because I want to get the string from a file. But it still doesn't work with the file?
$text=file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
file_get_contents is supposed to return a string, and the file exists, but it makes whole program not work??

Comment: file_get_contents("external_file.txt") works for me. Can you show me your txt file? Try not to have "return" in the external text file.

Comment: Ah it works now I put double quotes! Thanks.
Whats the logic on when to use single and double quotes :)

Comment: You could open another case or search for that question if you wanna know more. Basically, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes

```
alert('<?php echo $test; ?>');
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im still getting nothing if I use in PHP
$text=file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
file_get_contents is supposed to return a string, and the file exists, but it makes whole program not work??